# What justifies choosing a method or class?

Tags: oop, analysis

Say you need to reverse a String.

You could make a method called reverseString. But would you consider making a class called StringReverser ? If not, what criteria do you use to decide that a class needs to be made ?

P.S: This may touch the topic of systems analysis. If you are familiar with some questions or rules of thumb that answer the question clearly please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only make an instance class if you have instance-state: that is, if you're representing a persistent object in-memory.

I would only create a `StringReverser` class if the act of reversing a string required persistent state or configuration - but I can't think of any, so I wouldn't.

But consider the difference between the method `String.Concat(params String[] strings)` and the class `StringBuilder`, both do the same thing (concatenate strings together), but `StringBuilder` has state that you can pass between consumers, which is not something you can do with the `.Concat` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a judgement call.

Here, we are looking at a single function that performs a single operation and requires no state. Furthermore there's no need for [polymorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) behaviour. In these circumstances, I would create a static[1] class or a module called `StringUtils`, and would place the function there. I would place other similar functions into the same class/module.

[1] By "static", I mean a class that consists entirely of [static methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods).

Comment: Thanks. What is your reasoning here ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson: I've expanded the answer.